# SEO friendly CMS with user profile functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

My company has a project to create a magazine style site with user profile functionality. We need:

- CMS for the article publishing.
- SEO Friendly urls.
- Commenting capability for the published articles.
- User profile system with limited social networking functionality (friends,friend messages,blog,account tweaking/personalization, article commenting)

My area of expertise is asp.net, particularly MVC. I have read similar posts on this site regarding CMS with MVC and I'm surveying the landscape (N2, Kooboo, MvcCms, etc). What I am really interested in knowing is whether there are any platforms out there (WAMP or LAMP) that provide this functionality out of the box. I may be willing to go the LAMP route if it requires little development work. If I have to crack open any code then it probably needs to be .net unless there are compelling reasons to go another route.

Answer (score 0):

Like often when seeing a question about CMS in a [LW]AMP platform, I might suggest [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).

It's quite a nice tool, used by many websites, including quite big ones -- and has **a lot** of user-contributed modules.

About your requirements :

- article publishing : OK
- SEO friendly URLs : OK, with the [pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto)
- comments : OK
- user profile : OK with the [profile module](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/profile) *(Built-in, if I remember correctly)*

  - friends, messages, account personalization, ... : not sure about that, sorry.

One drawback ? It requires some time to master... But that's true for almost any tool I know, might I add.